# DNS Configurations for Microsoft VDI on Hyper-V Server 2012

Tags: hyper-v, domain-controller, vdi, dns-server

I'm trying to set up VDI using Hyper-V Server 2012. I have 2 physical machines, one Windows 8 client for remote management and another machine running a fresh copy of Hyper-V Server 2012. I'll be creating the VDI infrastructure on virtual machines on the Hyper-V server (1 domain controller, 1 connection broker, 1 virtualization host, and 1 web access server) and I'll be remotely managing the server from my Windows 8 client (the physical machines connected through the same WORKGROUP).

I have purchased mydomain.com from an internet registrar and would like to set up a domain controller for developer.mydomain.com (in one of the VMs) and join the other 3 VMs running the VDI infrastructure to that domain.

I'm struggling to understand what my DNS configurations should be on pretty much all 6 (physical and virtual) machines.

Should I use my ISP's DNS Servers for the client (already set by default) and physical hyper-v server (will have to set manually)? Again, they're connected through the same WORKGROUP.

For the VMs inside the physical server I understand the DC will act also as a DNS server so the DNS Server for those 4 machines will be the static IP of the DC VM (I think). But what settings do I need to adjust in my internet registrar's control panel for my DC to work correctly?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set your dns server as the dns server for all your machines. In your dns server, set the forwarder to your isp's dns server.

Unless you want your dns server to be resolving hosts for internet clients, you don't need to change anything with your isp.

Comment: Thank you. Won't that knock out the internet on my Windows 8 client whenever the domain controller is not running (if I turn off the server)? I'd like to manage the server from my computer but still retain normal internet functionality when the server is shut down.

Also, I did not say to change settings with my ISP, I said my internet registrar (ex, GoDaddy.com where I purchased mydomain.com).   If that's also what you meant, then how else will my users connect to their virtual desktop if the server can't be resolved over the internet? That is why I purchased mydomain.com to begin with.

Comment: On your Windows 8 box, set the secondary dns server to your isp's dns server.

Comment: Dns is a vital part off active directory. Generally, you don't want your active directory integrated dns exposed to the internet. That is too many internals to be allowed outside. The typical configuration is to let your isp host your external facing dns. You can host your own dns (larger companies will) but it might not be worth the hassle. That's your call.

Comment: Oh, and since you're using remote desktop gateway, your internal rdp hosts do not need to be externally resolveable. The gateway will handle name resolution for the hosts behind it.